# ASP.Net returning corrupted byte array to my application via WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I have an asp.net application(locally for testing) setup along with an FTP server with a file on it. I am trying to have my .exe get a byte array that my asp.net application gets from my FPT server. This works when I get the data directly from my FTP server from my .exe, the data from the file its download is correct. I tested this by getting the length. When I go return a the size of the byte array as a string from the asp.net application .exe->asp.net->ftp->asp.net->.exe the length of the byte array is 7. but if i go directly from the .exe to the ftp server .exe->ftp->.exe the length of the byte array is 47616 which is correct for the size of the file. Now the part that confuses me, if I go .exe->asp.net->ftp->asp.net->.exe by having the asp.net application return the byte array it downloaded from the ftp server to the .exe, if I get the length of the returned byte array it has a length of 63490. The file size is 46.5KB. Im just completely lost here, any insight would be wonderful, thank you!

edit: added more asp.net and .exe code.
more details: When I call mainFunction(which is c++ in a separate .dll) it will fail on the commented line below with the .dll data from the asp.net application since it acts like its not a valid .dll(i can assure you the .dll functions properly as intended. everything works properly until i tried to get the asp.net application to get the file data for me instead of it being in the .exe(which works as intended just fine). Ive also never used asp.net before this or even really looked into the use, but i do not really need it for any other purpose aside from downloading the .dll data and returning it to the .exe.

c++ .dll portion

```
bool ManualMap(HANDLE hProc, BYTE fileData[])
{
BYTE *                  pSrcData        = nullptr;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *      pOldNtHeader    = nullptr;
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER * pOldOptHeader   = nullptr;
IMAGE_FILE_HEADER *     pOldFileHeader  = nullptr;
BYTE *                  pTargetBase     = nullptr;

std::ifstream File("C:", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

auto FileSize = 53760;
pSrcData = new BYTE[static_cast<UINT_PTR>(FileSize)];

if (!pSrcData)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Memory allocating failed", NULL, NULL);
    return false;
}

pSrcData = fileData;
reinterpret_cast<char*>(pSrcData);

if (reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(pSrcData)->e_magic != 0x5A4D) //here
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Invalid File", NULL, NULL);
    delete[] pSrcData;
    return false;
}
```

asp.net

```
    public byte[] Get(string id)
    {
        WebClient WC = new WebClient();

        string FileName = "file.dll";
        string FTPURL = "ftp://address/";
        string Username = "username";
        string Password = "password";
        string CompletePath = FTPURL + FileName;

        try
        {
            WC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            return WC.DownloadData(new Uri(CompletePath));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }
```

.exe

```
    private bool InjectFile(byte[] Data)
    {
        return mainFunction(Data, "app.exe");
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] Data = WC.DownloadData(URL + "1");

        if (Data.Length > 0)
        {
            if (InjectFile(Data))
                MessageBox.Show("Injection Successful");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Injection Failed");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error retreiving file data from server");
    }
```

Comment: Long story short, the web app returns a bloated file in response to ... what? An HTTP GET? How are the results returned? Right now it's impossible to guess whether your application is MVC, Core ,Web API or WebForms, or how the results are treated. Instead of returing the data directly use `var bytes=WC.DownloadData(CompletePath);` so you can check the actual file size. Is that the expected size? If it is, what does the *rest* of the code do?

Comment: Please add relevant asp.net code

Comment: Updated main post.

Comment: @SneakyKittyGaming you still haven't mentioned whether this is ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI, Core or not. *Did* you debug your ASP.NET code? Is the data size correct *there*? If the FTP server returns a shorter or larger file, there's nothing to fix in the ASP.NET code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, The size of the file in the asp.net code shows the length of the byte array as 7. im using MVC i believe, i created this project a few weeks ago for another purpose and never ended up touching it until tonight when i decided to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Update ASP.NET action to return a file

```
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
    WebClient WC = new WebClient();

    string FileName = "file.dll";
    string FTPURL = "ftp://address/";
    string Username = "username";
    string Password = "password";
    string CompletePath = FTPURL + FileName;


    try
    {
        WC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
        return File(WC.DownloadData(new Uri(CompletePath)), "application/octet-stream");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return File(new byte[0], "application/octet-stream");
    }
}
```

Comment: `text/plain` would be an exceedingly bad choice for a DLL.

Comment: This *assumes* the stack and file type. If anything, `text/plain` will *cause* problems

Comment: @JeroenMostert I posted this before post was edited. Will rethink my asnwer

Comment: @JeroenMostert Updated. Is it ok now?

Comment: Random note that Im adding to the main post, Im only having the data of the file be loaded into memory and never actually written to disk. Ill give this a try and see if the filesize is correct tomorrow(its 4:43AM currently), thank you.